# Is there a math notation/ term for "$f(x_n) \to 0$ iff $g(x_n) \to 0$"?

Tags: limits, continuity, notation, terminology

I have two real-valued functions $f,g$ defined over the $N$-dimension Real Euclidean space:
$$
f,g: \mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}.
$$
They satisfy this property:
$$
\forall x_n \in \mathbb{R}^N: f(x_n)\to 0 \text{ if and only if } 
g(x_n)\to 0
$$
I am wondering whether there is a *mathematical notation/ term* for naming such a property? I thought about using $f=O(g)$, but it turns out to mean something different from the above property. I also thought about using terms like continuity, etc.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe $(f,g)(x_n)\to 0$

Comment: You wrote $\forall x_n \in \mathbb{R}^N: f(x_n)\to 0 \text{ if and only if }g(x_n)\to 0$. This doesn't make sense. Did you mean $\forall (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \left(\mathbb{R}^N\right)^\mathbb{N}: f(x_n)\to 0 \text{ if and only if }g(x_n)\to 0$

Comment: @Xaver. Thanks. Mathematics is a language for communication, so, I do not see there is such a need to further obscure the notation (as what you proposed) when it can already be well understood.

Comment: Are the functions continuous?

Comment: Possibly over-complicating, you can say something like "$f^{-1}((-1/n,1/n))$ and $g^{-1}((-1/n,1/n))$ are equivalent as filter bases" (which also implies either both are or both aren't filter bases). If both $f$ and $g$ are continuous the condition is equivalent to $f^{-1}(0) = g^{-1}(0)$.